# Why does the truncateTable() method create an empty string for a query and fail to delete rows?

Tags: development, database, jdatabase

I have the following code attempting to truncate a table. The Joomla documentation makes me believe this will work, but it does not. What am I missing?

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
truncate_query = $db->getQuery(true);
//$truncate_query = 'TRUNCATE ' . $db->quoteName('#__mytable');
$truncate_query->truncateTable($db->quoteName('#__mytable'));
$db->setQuery($truncate_query);
echo $truncate_query;
exit();
```

The echo statement displays nothing. If I use the line that is commented out to manually generate the SQL, it does work.

The reason I am looking to use the `truncateTable()` function is that I am trying to include the truncation in a transaction. When I use the manual `TRUNCATE` statement, the table is still truncated even if another part of the transaction fails.  This is annoying since the other statements rely on the success of the truncation; so, if the table is emptied when it shouldn't be there is no data left to run the transaction again.

Comment: Not tested by maybe try adding `$query->execute();` at the end, after `$db->setQuery($truncate_query);`?

Comment: I have the execute statement in the actual code. The echo statement is blank, so it wouldn't matter anyway ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

It appears that the `setQuery()` and `execute()` calls are already inside the function scope...

From https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/database/driver.php

> ```
> /**
>  * Method to truncate a table.
>  *
>  * @param   string  $table  The table to truncate
>  *
>  * @return  void
>  *
>  * @since   11.3
>  * @throws  RuntimeException
>  */
> public function truncateTable($table)
> {
>     $this->setQuery('TRUNCATE TABLE ' . $this->quoteName($table));
>     $this->execute();
> }
> ```

### So this is how you call/execute the truncation (I just tested this and it works):

```
class modTrunctestHelper
{
    public function deleteAllRows(){
        JFactory::getDbo()->truncateTable('#__guineapig');
    }
}
```

I also posted [an answer on your replicated Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435741/2943403) with different wording.

---

Original post:

I believe this issue/bug should be brought to the attention of the Joomla core developers.

I can confirm that I was able to reproduce the problem.

I ran `->truncateTable()` on my `#__guineapig` table and included some checkpoints along the way:

```
class modTrunctestHelper
{
    public function deleteAllRows(){
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        try {
            $truncate = $db->getQuery(true)
                           ->truncateTable('#__guineapig');
            // $truncate = 'TRUNCATE #__guineapig';
            // $truncate = $db->getQuery(true)
            //                ->delete('#__guineapig');
            echo $truncate->dump();
            $db->setQuery($truncate);
            $db->execute();
            echo $db->getAffectedRows() , 'Rows Of Data Deleted';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Syntax Error" , $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
$TT = new modTrunctestHelper();
$TT->deleteAllRows();
```

1. If I wrote: `echo $truncate->dump();` the script broke and said:

   > Fatal error: Call to a member function dump() on null
2. If I removed `->dump()` to avoid the error, then nothing useful can come from executing a `null` string as a query (duh), the page displayed:

   > Syntax Error
3. By running the raw query `TRUNCATE #__guineapig` (via `setQuery()` then `execute()`), all rows were deleted and the auto-incremented index was reset as expected.  For the record, `$db->getNumRows()` is inappropriate and doesn't work; while `$db->getAffectedRows()` produced a count of `0` because the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/truncate-table.html) says:

   > Truncation operations do not return a meaningful value for the number of deleted rows.
4. If you are desperate (and I don't think you need to be) to use [JDatabase Methods](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase), then you *could* use `delete()` which will speak to `getAffectedRows()` but this is a completely different process with different behaviors.  Notably, `DELETE` queries don't reset the auto-increment number.  See my earlier link to the manual to see exactly what `TRUNCATE` queries do.